# SQL azure support user defined table type?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, defined, sql-types

My question is does SQL azure supports user defined table type?
It gets created but raised an error while using in Stored Proc. as unsupported data type..

Please Suggest

Answer (score 0):

yes sql azure supports user defined table type.

Comment: Hi.. User Defined table type is created..But when we execute the SP which uses the  User Defined Table Type it raises the error UnSupported data Type Please Suggest..